# BasicAF : Project: Tip Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

these are the parameters of the project:

#If the bill was $150.00, split between 5 people, with 12% tip.

#Each person should pay (150.00 / 5) * 1.12 = 33.6

#Format the result to 2 decimal places = 33.60

***pleae keep in mind you may have a soulution that uses some advance code I many not be familiar with.

```
bill = input("What is the total bill?")

# bill is 150.00

tip = input("What percentage tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15?")

# tip will be 12%

max_tip = float(tip) / 100

# split between 5 people
people = input("How many people to split the bill?")

max_split = int(bill) / int(people)
max_cost = int(max_split) * float(max_tip)

print(f"Each person should pay:{max_cost}")
```

this is my current output:

What is the total bill?150
What percentage tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15?12
How many people to split the bill?5
Each person should pay:3.5999999999999996

I know from earlier lessons you can round(number, 2) and that should signify to python to round two place pass the decimal.

float(max_tip, 2) it was the only place that made sense to me. but then my out put was:

line 77, in 
max_cost = int(max_split) * float(max_tip, 2)
TypeError: float expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Process finished with exit code 1

thank you for any tips and advice. I appreciate it.

I tired to figure this out on my own using just what I have learned so far. But I cannot figure out how to round up two places pass the decimal.

Also, how do I turn 0.12% into 1.12?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure entirely what you are wanting from this question but here are some fixes to your code. First you wanted to know how to round, you would use the `round()` method with it's first parameter the number and the second parameter being how many places you would like to round to. You also asked about changing .12% into 1.12 all you would do it `(tip / 100) + 1`. I have added these changes to the code below:

```
bill = float(input("What is the total bill?"))
tip = int(input("What percentage tip would you like to give? 10, 12, or 15?"))
people = int(input("How many people to split the bill?"))

decimal_multiplier = tip / 100 + 1
max_split = bill / people
max_cost = round((max_split * decimal_multiplier), 2)

print(f"Each person should pay: {max_cost}")
```

Comment: so when I run your code I get. 33.6, however, I need it to say 33.60

Comment: You would need to use the `format` function so after `max_cost` variable you would add another line that says:
`
formatted_cost = "{:.2f}".format(maxcost)
`
Then change the print statement to print `formatted_cost`

Comment: that was perfect! thank you so much I've been trying for a few days now to get this correct. thank you all for the help tip and advise.